# My code is jumping to a function when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, winforms

Below is my program for keeping track of Volunteers. My problem is, with the two functions below, when `fillListBoxData()` is called, about halfway through it jumps to the `fillDataGridView` function. On the 15th line, `dataAda1.Fill(datTab3);` the program immediately jumps to `fillDataGridView(string fullName)`. I have no idea why.

Could someone help me out, and get this program to stop doing that.

```
public void fillListBoxData()
    {
        //Open connection
        //found in app.config
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))//database ONE
        {
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();

            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (firstName + ' ' + lastName) AS NAME FROM dbo.VolunteerContactInfo", conn))
            {
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable datTab3 = new DataTable();
                dataAda1.Fill(datTab3);                

                //assign the dataTable as the dataSource for the listbox
                volList.DataSource = datTab3;
                //display member needed to show text
                volList.DisplayMember = "NAME";
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
    }

void fillDataGridView(string fullName)
    {
        string tableName = "dbo." + fullName;
        // Open connection
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString))//database TWO
        {
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();

            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + @tableName, conn))
            {
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable datTab = new DataTable();
                dataAda.Fill(datTab);

                volWorkDataGrid.DataSource = datTab;

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it's jumping to `fillDataGridView`?

Comment: It's possible that your method `fillDataGridView` is being registered as an event handler for your grid, and it's being called by the grid during the fill.  You'll need to remove that event handler to keep it from getting called.

Comment: Could also be possible that when you are debugging you debugger is jumping betwixt threads.

Comment: @Kevin  I know it's jumping to fillDataGridView because I watched it in the debugging mode of visual studio. And that function is crashing my program because it's not letting fillListBoxData() finish.

Comment: Take a look at your stack trace while in the `fillDataGridView` to see what's making the call.

Comment: It's also possible that the debugger isn't showing the proper source code.  If you have a compilation error and debug the last compiled version.

Comment: @NathanA, I would, but I don't know how to look at the "stack trace".

Comment: Call stack in the debugger = stack trace

Comment: While in debug mode, look for the tab called Call Stack.

Comment: I would think you have a listbox that when the selected value changes it calls fillDataGridView and on loading because is changing on each loaded value it is loading data to the grid at each step. Just guessing here, I could be way off.

Comment: Okay. I found part of the issue. when `volList.DataSource = datTab3` happens, the event `volList_SelectedIndexChanged` occcurs, and a line in that event is `fillDataGridView(dataGridViewName);` Though I don't know how to counter that...

Comment: You can always use a temporary bool flag to suppress the handling of your SelectedIndexChanged event until you are done "initializing"

Comment: Look at other events to use mouse down, key up something that is not fired just on changes.

Comment: @N4TKD, Problem is, I want the info to change on both a mouse click and if the user wants to use the arrow keys/tab.

Comment: @NathanA, how would I set a temporary bool flag?

Comment: @user3599400 ok so you can call a method from both mouse down and key down, would be one option to do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary flag to suppress the event handler while you are "initializing" your data.

```
bool _suppressEvent = false;

public void fillListBoxData() 
{
    try
    {
         _suppressEvent = true;

         ...Do whatever you want here
    }
    finally
    {
        _suppressEvent = false;
    }
}

void volList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( _suppressEvent ) return;

    ...
}
```

The try/finally ensures that no matter what happens inside the try clause (exceptions, returns, etc), your suppression flag will always get turned off.  Otherwise, you may get some strange behaviors that are hard to track down.

Comment: My program is still not working as intended, but this will get me moving in the right direction. Thanks!